# How can I find out which app changes file associations in OS X 10.8

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, file-association

I'm not sure how, but some app is changing the file associations on my machine automatically.  It is becoming very frustrating.  Is there a way I can track what application is doing this?

What makes it really strange is that I don't use these 'newly defaulted' applications.  For example, I never use Safari, but somehow it is set as my default browser.  So I set Chrome as my default browser and a day later, the same thing happens.

I find that the file association on my media is changing as well to an esoteric video editing software which I don't use.

How can I go about figure out what's going on?  I just figured maybe when the file association is changed it is logged somewhere.  I took a look at `/var/log/system.log` but didn't see anything that could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember when this started?

File and URI associations are set in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` under the `LSHandlers` key, and not on a per-app basis. To check what process changes this file's contents, you could install [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) and let it run in the background for a while.

This will gather lots of information, but you can filter it to the `com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` file. Here, for example, you can see how the `cfprefsd` changed the file. In this case, it's a deliberate change I did using [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/), which in the background uses the [CFPreferences agent process](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.html) to modify the plist file.

[image]

With more information about this process, you could track down what's changing the associations.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response.  I'm going to install fseventer and see what it tells me.  It first happend on Nov 29, once again on Dec 1 and then today.